# New upgraded Ubuntu 18.10 boots to blank screen (nvidia graphics card)

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg, wayland, 18.10

After the upgrade, the system boots to a blank screen. Cntrl+Alt+F1/F2 doesn't do anything ... but the system is running, I can ssh to it, and ALT+PrtScr+B will trigger a reboot.

Doing an SSH the system does start wayland (it is running), but the screen is blank.

Things I tried:

- When booting at recovery mode, the screen freezes after a while. I suspect the system is running (since I can do Alt+PrtScr+B to reboot), but something it starts that is not the console is not working -- I can't check since it doesn't start sshd, and I can't login to the machine.
- Nvidia driver version is 410. But i just tried the 390 as well.
- I tried starting Xorg manually (/usr/bin/Xorg) from my ssh, and it works. I just run /usr/bin/Xorg (root) and then set DISPLAY=:0.0 and gnome-shell and I get a working Xwindows for rooot.
- I also tried a newest kernel (4.19-rc8 I think) recommended in another post, but didn't help.

Any suggestions ? Any error messages / files I should be looking at ?

Is there a way to make gdm work with Xorg instead of Xwayland until it works ?

many thanks in advance for any pointers!

ps.: I've seen a bunch of similar questions, but none of the answers seem relevant.

Answer (score 2):

After some more digging, I found how to force gdm to use only Xorg:

- Edit `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`
- Uncomment line with `WaylandEnable=false`

Now the system is usable again -- albeit without Xwayland.